# Error Your startup project doesn't reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a project is web.API.
I try to make migration but it is not working. I found a lot of solutions but they are not is working. Also ı looked at similar threads opened on stackoverflow and did what was said, but did not get any results.

class libary has dbcontext .csproj

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Repositories\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.12">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.12">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Core\SharedNote.Domain\SharedNote.Domain.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

my dbcontext class

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SharedNote.Domain.Entites;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SharedNotes.Persistence.Context
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected ApplicationDbContext()
        {

        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (optionsBuilder.IsConfigured == false)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SHARED_NOTE;User ID=sa;Password=stacoverflow");
            }
        }
        public DbSet<College> Colleges { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FileDocument> FileDocuments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    }
}
```

my web.apı csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Core\SharedNote.Application\SharedNote.Application.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Infrastructure\SharedNotes.Persistence\SharedNotes.Persistence.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

error from pmc

note:my default project is "src/Infrastructure/SharedNotes.Persistence" in pmc

```
PM> add-migration initial-v1.0
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Your startup project 'ShareableNote.API' doesn't reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design. This package is required for the Entity Framework Core Tools to work. Ensure your startup project is correct, install the package, and try again.
PM>
```

Comment: Have you selected the API project as startup project?

Comment: yes ı did but it gives same error

Comment: Also you need to select the project as default project which has ApplicationDbContext class in PMC

Comment: yes ı did, my default project is "src/Infrastructure/SharedNotes.Persistence" in pmc it has applicationdbcontext

Comment: Show your startup.cs file

Comment: Thank you, i detected a problem in somewhere. ı fixed it

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: problem is wrong service name. I added other service extension method to startup.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your api project should have Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

```
ItemGroup>

    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />

   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.12">

</ItemGroup>
```

and as I understand it is your first migration, so in console manager select your dbcontext project and try this

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
```

Comment: `PM> add-migration initial-v1.0
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
PM> `

Comment: I did this method. It gives this error

Comment: @notcontrol It is a different question already. You first error was about EntityFrameworkCore.Design